# Real analysis: Convergence and limits of a sequence/subsequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

Let $P_{nk}$ be real numbers (with $n, k \in \mathbb{N}$) satisfying the 
following:

(a) $P_{nk}≥0$ for all $n, k$

(b) $\sum_{k=1}^{n} P_{nk}=1$ for all $n$

(c) $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} P_{nk}=0$ for all $k$

Let $(x_{n})$ be a convergent sequence and let a sequence $(y_{n})$ be defined by

$y_{n}=\sum_{k=1}^{n} P_{nk}x_{k}$

Prove that $(y_{n})$ is a convergent sequence and that

$\lim y_{n}=\lim x_{n}$

I'm thinking of trying to prove that $(y_{n})$ is a subsequence of $(x_{n})$ using conditions (a), (b), and (c), then use the fact that a subsequence of a convergent sequence also converges to the same limit...

Comment: But $(y_n)$ is not a subsequence of $(x_n)$. Hint: The good'old epsilon-delta method (or, in this case, epsilon-N...) works like a charm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's denote $\lim_n x_n$ by $x$, evaluate and estimate the difference between $y_n$ and $x$ as follows:
\begin{align*}
|y_n - x| = & \left|\sum_{k = 1}^n P_{nk}x_k - x\right| \\
= & \left|\sum_{k = 1}^n P_{nk}x_k - x_n + x_n - x\right| \\
= & \left|\sum_{k = 1}^n P_{nk}x_k - \sum_{k = 1}^n P_{nk}x_n + x_n - x\right| \\
\leq & \sum_{k = 1}^n P_{nk}|x_k - x_n| + |x_n - x| \tag{1}
\end{align*}
Now you need some classic $\varepsilon$-$N$ argument. Given $\varepsilon > 0$, since $\lim_n x_n = x$, there exists $N$ sufficiently large such that $|x_n - x| < \varepsilon$ for all $n \geq N$ and $\sup_{k, n \geq N}|x_n - x_k| < \varepsilon$ (by Cauchy convergence criterion). Also, since $\{x_n\}$ is convergent, it is bounded, so it can be assumed that there exists $M > 0$ such that $|x_n| \leq M$ for all $n$. Now for all $n > N$, $(1)$ reads
\begin{align*}
|y_n - x| \leq & \sum_{k = 1}^{N} P_{nk}|x_k - x_n| + \sum_{k = N + 1}^n P_{nk}|x_k - x_n| + \varepsilon \\
\leq & 2M\sum_{k = 1}^N P_{nk} + \varepsilon \sum_{k = 1}^n P_{nk} + \varepsilon \\
= & 2M\sum_{k = 1}^N P_{nk} + 2\varepsilon.
\end{align*}
where we used conditions (a) and (b) during the derivation. By condition (c), the first term in the right side of the above inequality tends to $0$ as $n \to \infty$, since $N$ is a finite number. Therefore $|y_n - x|$ can be made arbitrarily small for all sufficiently large $n$, and the proof is complete.

You may make the proof looks even more rigorous by multiplying some constants of $\varepsilon$ and choose $N'$ more carefully.

Comment: Thank you very much! Excellent answer.